# Getting square boxes instead of text in Chromium save as menu

Tags: ubuntu

When ever I try to save or download something, on the save menu there is not text instead there are boxes everywhere. This happens only when I'm selecting path for my downloads or if I'm selecting files to upload in chromium. I have tried so many solutions but they didn't work. I'm using ubuntu 20.04LTS & chromium version 83.[image]

Comment: see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1224125/font-characters-displayed-as-squares-in-ubuntu-18-04 or https://askubuntu.com/questions/1103560/only-squares-instead-of-letters-and-numbers-are-displayed-in-my-calculator-and-o

Comment: @pLumo Thank you soo much. One of these solution worked for me. :)

Comment: @pLumo Hi, sorry to bother you again. but I didn't do anything special after trying those steps and this whole thing came up again.

Answer (score 0):

Try below commands

```
fc-cache -fr
sudo reboot
```

This work for me too.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Would you mind explaining _why_ that would solve the OPs problem?